# Getting a blank page when injecting the $resource method

Tags: angularjs

The below code is working only when removing the ngResource and $resource injection.
I want to know why the below code is failing as Iam included all the necessary JS files for the resource method. we cann't inject both $resource and $http method together?

### Service (using $http method)

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('angApp',['ngResource']).constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:3000/")
        .factory('AccountFactory', ['$http', 'baseUrl', '$resource',function ( $http, baseUrl, $resource) {

            var accountObj = {};

            accountObj.getAllAccounts = function () {
                return $http.get(baseUrl + "getAllAccounts");

            };

            return accountObj;


        }]);
```

---

### call from the controller :-

```
AccountFactory.getAllAccounts().then(function (response) {...}
```

I want to implement the same thing using $resource method. But it is giving a blank screen and not able to proceed further (injection itself failing.)
I tried below code.

### service (using $resource method)

```
angular.module('angApp',['ngResource']).constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:3000/")
        .factory('AccountFactory', ['baseUrl', '$resource',function ( baseUrl, $resource) {
    var accountObj = {};

                var accounts = $resource(baseUrl + "getAllAccounts",
                    {
                        userId: '@id'
                    }
                );

                accountObj.getAllAccounts = function () {
                    accounts.get(function (req) {
                        console.log("success");
                    }, function (req) {
                        console.log("failure");
                    });
                }

                return accountObj;

        }]);
```

(similar to the $http method). Please correct me if am doing anything wrong in the above implementation. How will I call this function from the controller?

Comment: Not getting any error in the browser console.

Comment: Does the query execute? Check the Network tab in Chrome Developer tools for a query that matches the URL and method. There you should see the server response, including the data